# react client side rendering error cannot get /

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am attempting to learn react and I am coming to some issues when attempting client side routing. Please let me know if you see the mistake I have in my files listed.The error I keep getting on the browser page is

Cannot GET /

The error I see in my console is:

live.bundle.js:14 GET http://localhost:8080/ 404 (Not Found)

Here are my files:

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './js/app.js'
  ],
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js?$/, loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel', 'babel-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/ },
      // { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./src/www",
    noInfo: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>New React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="react"></section>
    <script src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

/js/app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-router';
import {DefaultRoute, Link, Route, RouteHandler} from 'react-router';

import LoginHandler from './components/Login.js';

class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="nav">

        <Link to="app">Home</Link>
        <Link to="login">Login</Link>

        {/* Important Part */}
        <RouteHandler/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

let routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <Route name="login" path="/login" handler={LoginHandler}/>
  </Route>
);

ReactDOM.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

/js/components/Login.js

```
import React from 'react';
class Login extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return(
      <div>Welcome to login</div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

I appreciate the help.

Here is my webpack.config.js file updated according to @Frederick Mfinanga

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './js/app.js',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?localhost:8080'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js?$/, loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel', 'babel-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/ },
      // { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    // contentBase: "./src/www",
    noInfo: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Comment: Have you checked whether your app creates the output file `bundle.js`? If it doesn't then that's the reason. It simply can't find that specific file and because you import it in `index.html` file that's the problem in your code. So make sure that the `bundle.js` file is created.

Comment: Hi Amir, my app is creating the bundle.js file inside a folder called build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove

```
contentBase: "./src/www",
```

from your devServer config. This will by default serve the files in your current directory. which i believe is what you are looking for and where your index.html lives? correct?

Comment: Hello Frederick,  I added this part because if I take it out I get the error "Uncaught Error: [HMR] Hot Module Replacement is disabled". Do you still suggest I do this? If so, how can I solve the error I just listed? Also, I do want to serve my index.html file and is is where my index.html lives.

Comment: yes still do it and add this line to your entry array. 
'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080', 

change the port accordingly
and add this to your plugins array new Webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()

Comment: I followed your suggestion. The url I put in my browser is "localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/#";. I still get the error "Uncaught Error: [HMR} Hot Module Replacement is disabled", I have updated my question to show your modifications on the webpack.config.js file. Please let me know if I have misunderstood your directions.

Comment: Add the --inline flag when running your script.

Comment: So instead of "npm start" run "npm start --inline"? If so, I attempted that and still have the error "Uncaught Error: [HMR] Hot Module Replacement is disabled."

Comment: It seems to work once I did webpack --inline. However, I recieved another error stating that ReactDOM is not defined. Oh well, it seems this issue is solved. Thanks Frederick!

Comment: no problem. npm install react-dom, import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; on the file you use it